# IEnumerable Property can't return the value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have ViewModel

```
public class Magazine_ViewModel
{
    public int MagId { get; set; }
    public string MagNo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Titles_ViewModel> Titles { get; set; }
}

public class Titles_ViewModel
{
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public string TitleName { get; set; }
    public int pos { get; set; }
}
```

in Controller  i do like this

```
        var viewModel = new Magazine_ViewModel
        {
            Titles = numberTitles
                .Select(c => new Titles_ViewModel
                {
                    TitleId = c.TitleId,
                    TitleName = c.Title.TitleText,
                    pos=c.position
                }).ToList()
        };                    
        viewModel.MagNo = magazine.MagNo.ToString();
        viewModel.MagId = magazine.Id;
```

when i check viewModel.Titles  has n records which is right.
now in the view part

```
     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MagNo)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MagNo)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.ListBox("wholeTitles")
     <input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="add" onclick="addValue()" /><input type="button" name="remove" id="remove" value="remove"  onclick="removeValue()"/>
      @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Titles, new SelectList(Model.Titles, "TitleId", "TitleName"))
    </div>
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
```

I add new Titles from first ListBox(wholeTitles) to second ListBox(Titles). Now the submit button is press and i want to add the new Titles to the database.

This is what i do in Post Action

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTitle(Magazine_ViewModel magazineViewModel)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var magazineTitles = new Magazine
            {
                Id = magazineViewModel.MagId,
                NumberTitles = new List<NumberTitle>()
            };

            foreach (var numberTitle in magazineViewModel.Titles)
            {

                    NumberTitle newNumberTitle = new NumberTitle();
                    newNumberTitle.MagazineId = magazineViewModel.MagId;
                    newNumberTitle.TitleId = numberTitle.TitleId;
                    newNumberTitle.position = 0;
                    unitOfWork.NumberTitleRepository.Insert(newNumberTitle);

            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

but magazineViewModel.Titles shows null, I don't know what should I check to see why it is null value.

Comment: Do you have your Submit wrap in Html.BeginForm?, If so can you please update the code how it looks like. Also what's POST Action method signature looks like?

Comment: Yes it is inside section BeginForm. when i submit the EditTitle gets focus magazineViewModel has value for MagNo and MagId but Titles is null

Comment: I think if you use hidden fields you can pass the values back to the server. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your values not get posted back to the server. Use below in your View. This should post the titles back to the Server within the same ViewModel

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Titles.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Titles[i].TitleId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Titles[i].TitleName)
    }
```